# Inconsistent Lambda AWS Runtimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have created an Amazon Web Services Lambda Function in python and added code to get the execution time because we noticed that the runtime is varying significantly based on how long it has been since the last lambda call and provision concurrency seems to have little impact. For all the runs in the table below, we were running the same lambda with the same inputs and the program is deterministic, so everything related to our code is held constant. Below is a table of what we found. Interval means how long we waited before making another call to the lambda; for example 2 hours means that if we called a lambda at 1:00 PM, we called it again at 3:00 PM and 5:00 PM etc. (but not in between). # Invocations is the total number of times the lambda was called in succession for a given interval.

| Provisioned Concurrency | Interval | # Invocations | Avg Duration | p90 Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| off | 2 hours | 42 | 17.9 sec | 32.0 sec |
| off | 10 minutes | 304 | 14.6 sec | 21.2 sec |
| off | 1 minute | 364 | 4.5 sec | 6.3 sec |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| on | 2 hours | 50 | 18.1 sec | 31.2 sec |
| on | 10 minutes | 49 | 10.2 sec | 29.6 sec |
| on | 1 minute | 404 | 4.6 sec | 6.3 sec |

So, a few questions that seem odd that maybe someone else has experience or knows something about:

1. We thought there would be a "hot" versus "cold" setting for the lambdas where provision concurrency would keep the lambdas "hot" all the time. However, 10 minutes versus 2 hours seems to be in a "warm" state (i.e. 10 minutes is faster than 2 hours, but not much faster). Then, at 1 minute, the lambda appears to be "hot" and consistently fast. Any idea what is going on here?
2. Also, we thought that provisioned concurrency would essentially make the lambda stay in the "hot" state regardless of invocation interval; however, that is not the case as can be seen with the 2 hour interval actually taking slightly longer. Having said that though, the 10 minute interval is slightly shorter with provision concurrency on.

Any help/incite on this is greatly appreciated.

**Extra information based on comments:**

1. The Lambda is triggered via API Gateway from an HTTP POST request.
2. The runtime is a custom Docker image. We are doing this so we can use a particular version of Tensorflow.
3. The Lambda does use other services: S3 and DynamoDB. We added logs to time each section, and we have identified that the majority of the time spent is inside of our self-contained section. Meaning, it doesn’t appear that S3 download/upload or DynamoDB read/write is taking much time at all. Most of the time is spent in our CPU intensive algorithm, which does image processing with Tensoflow. For those familiar with Deep Learning, the program loads a trained model and we do inference with that model and each test used the same image as input.
4. We’ve also tried adjusting the CPU/Memory of the lambda, and found it doesn’t seem to improve much beyond a certain point, and it does not fix the problem. The experiments from the table were gathered using 4GB Lambdas, and our logs report that less than 1GB of memory is ever used.

Comment: What does the code do? Connect to any external services/databases? Run anything that's CPU-intensive? Is it truly self-contained without any outside connectivity?

Comment: I have to agree with @Maurice. There is a lot of details missing. For example: which runtime are you using? Do you use in-memory caches? What about external services you use? You can make a lot of mistakes in your code where no provisioned concurrency would help you or stuff that your _runtime_ does to be "clever" that bites you after two hours etc. But one thing to note: provisioned concurrency does not mean that the same Lambda is running 24/7 for you. It just means that there is always at least n instances running. But they are also re-created from time to time.

Comment: Add logging to each step of processing the lambda does. This is most likely not a lambda issue but a code issue or some external service issue.

Comment: It also depends on how you are triggering the Lambdas. Are they invoked in parallel or serially?

Comment: Thank you for the comments and questions all! I added some additional clarifications to the post that hopefully answer your questions.